# Multiple inputs and one output in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I am very new in using TF. I would like build a model with 6 input and 1 output. My code is available below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

abalone_train = pd.read_csv("sipm2.csv",
    names=["Hit1", "Time1", "Hit2", "Time2", "Hit3",
           "Time3", "PosX"])

abalone_train.head()

abalone_features = abalone_train.copy()
abalone_labels = abalone_features.pop('PosX')

abalone_features = np.array(abalone_features)

print(abalone_features)

abalone_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.Dense(64),
  layers.Dense(64)
])

abalone_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1), metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
                      
history = abalone_model.fit(abalone_features, abalone_labels, epochs=100)

abalone_model.summary()

print("Finished training the model")

#plt.xlabel('Epoch Number')
#plt.ylabel("Loss Magnitude")
#plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
#plt.show()

posx_prediction = abalone_model.predict([75., 1., 75. ,1.3 ,66. ,2.])

print(posx_prediction)
```

The error I got is:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 6) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 6), dtype=tf.float32, name='dense_input'), name='dense_input', description="created by layer 'dense_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None,).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sertac/Work/TensorFlow/test3.py", line 39, in <module>
    posx_prediction = abalone_model.predict([75., 1., 75. ,1.3 ,66. ,2.])
  File "/Users/sertac/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/Users/sertac/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 1147, in autograph_handler
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/Users/sertac/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1801, in predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/Users/sertac/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1790, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/Users/sertac/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1783, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "/Users/sertac/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1751, in predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    File "/Users/sertac/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/Users/sertac/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 228, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential" (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)
    
    Call arguments received:
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=float32)
      • training=False
      • mask=None
```

I would like appreciate if you could help me how to get prediction?

Thanks in advance.

Sipm2.csv

104.241,1.12209,67.51,1.30428,57.354,1.48099,3.9
104.796,1.12425,67.787,1.3103,58.31,1.47481,3.5
103.203,1.10605,67.039,1.29599,56.825,1.47089,3.0
84.857,1.12028,80.898,1.23234,62.08,1.39148,2.5
86.015,1.16361,80.656,1.20233,62.945,1.37363,1.5
83.987,1.20226,80.211,1.17464,62.002,1.36756,1.0
85.35,1.21761,81.777,1.15021,62.541,1.34058,0.5

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns). They have a similar example.

Answer (score 0):

For 6 input and 1 output, your model should look something like below.

```
abalone_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.Input(shape=(6,))
  layers.Dense(64),
  layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax')
])
```